# SpriteKit scene/node on top a paused scene

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, scene

I'm trying to add a scene/node on top of a paused scene with a transparent background so the active scene view will still be visible.

I pause the scene with `scene.view.paused = YES;` but that means that everything is paused but the update method.

With `Cocos2d` one could easily push a new scene on top of an existing one but unfortunately `SpriteKit` does not have this capability.

Is there a way to pause a scene and add an active scene/node on top of it ?

**A solution I've tried :**

Creating an additional view controller with the pause-scene content and present it via the active view controller when needed but the background is always black so transparency is not achieved and some other problems occur with the original scene (I'll elaborate on these if needed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all there. You do not have to present a new scene or view.

In a nutshell:

- Pause the node where your game content is on that you want to pause. If you do all the processing in the scene class you'll have to refactor it, I'm afraid. The key is having a SKNode that acts as your "game layer" so that you can pause just that particular node. If you receive update: and other regular method calls to the game layer, it should check its self.paused state before doing any processing.
- When you have that, pause the game layer node which will pause all the nodes and actions in it.
- Now add another "layer" node with whatever UI you need to the scene. That could be your game over or pause layer, and it will be perfectly happy to receive input and run actions while the game layer is paused.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that point! I was sure that only a scene can be paused. Suddenly all seems clear and obvious;). Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I believe the scene.view.paused got me thinking that only a scene can be paused since a node does not have the view property